# Escape single quote in ssh command

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to send a sed command using ssh.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IP_PUBLIC="192.168.0.1"
from="DB_HOST='my_host'"
to="DB_HOST='192.168.0.2'"
    
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no root@"$IP_PUBLIC" '
    sed -i "s/'"$from'"/'"$to'"/g" /path/to/file;
'
```

Which throw me the following error:

```
test: line 9: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
test: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I also tried

```
#!/bin/bash

IP_PUBLIC="192.168.0.1"

ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no root@"$IP_PUBLIC" '
    sed -i "s/DB_HOST=\'my_host\'/DB_HOST=\'192.168.0.2\'/g" /path/to/file;
'
```

I got the same error

Content of the file

```
#!/bin/bash
DB_HOST='my_host'
```

Need to be

```
#!/bin/bash
DB_HOST='192.168.0.2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of thinking how to double escape stuff, use stdin and pass the actual variables with bash `declare -p` and functions with `declare -f`.

```
IP_PUBLIC="192.168.0.1"
from="DB_HOST='my_host'"
to="DB_HOST='192.168.0.2'"
work() {
    sed -i "s/$from/$to/g" /path/to/file;
}
    
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no root@"$IP_PUBLIC" bash -s <<EOF
$(declare -p from to)  # hand-pick transfer variable values
$(declare -f work)     # hand-pick transfer code
# everything is properly quoted, as it would be on localhost
work                   # execute the function.
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't use `bash -s` because I have other commands in there like `systemctl start snmpd;`

Comment: sooooo just `work() { sed -i "s/$from/$to/g" /path/to/file; other command like; systemctl start snmpd; }`. Put them in the function. Or just put them before `EOF` - I do not follow how does that affect not using `bash -s`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the variable `$from` and `$to` are part of a single quote string(`'`) bash won't expand them to the values.

[When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable/27701642)

Please try the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

IP_PUBLIC="192.168.0.1"
from="DB_HOST='my_host'"
to="DB_HOST='192.168.0.2'"

ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no root@"$IP_PUBLIC" "sed -i \"s/${from}/${to}/g\" /path/to/file;"
```